# Weird "The file '/DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx' does not exist" error when remapping WebService HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have dynamic CMS-driven (custom rolled, I know, wheels, etc. but not my decision!) site, which uses an HttpModule to direct content. I have found that .asmx resources were not working. After investigation, I figured out that this was because I had essentially overridden the handler by taking the request out of the overall pipeline.

So I am now detecting if the resource exists and is an .asmx file, and handling accordingly. Which I think is to create a WebServiceHandler using WebServiceHandlerFactory and then remapping it.

This works fine with a ?wsdl querystring, but ask for the URI itself and you get (at point indicated by asterisks):

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Failed to handle request. 
>   [snip]
>      InnerException:
>       System.InvalidOperationException
>          Message=Unable to handle request.
>          Source=System.Web.Services 
>          InnerException: System.Web.HttpException
>               Message=The file '/DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx' does not
>   exist.

Note the final InnerException. This [thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1427776/3190476.aspx/1?Re%20Nasty%20error%20attempting%20to%20create%20a%20simple%20Web%20Service) appears to suggest a corrupt .NET Framework install, but the file is present in the 4.0 Config folder. I suspect a mistake on my part. Am I remapping incorrectly?

```
public class xxxVirtualContentHttpModule : xxxHttpModule
{
        protected override void OnBeginRequest(IxxxContextProvider cmsContext, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            string resolvePath = httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

            // is path a physical file?
            IRootPathResolver rootPathResolver=new HttpServerRootPathResolver(httpContext.Server);
            string serverPath = rootPathResolver.ResolveRoot("~" + resolvePath);

            if (File.Exists(serverPath))
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(serverPath).Equals(".asmx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    WebServiceHandlerFactory webServiceHandlerFactory = new WebServiceHandlerFactory();
                    IHttpHandler webServiceHttpHandler = webServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(httpContext, "Get", resolvePath, serverPath); // *****

                    httpContext.RemapHandler(webServiceHttpHandler);
                }
            }

        }
```

*Update*

I have removed all references to the HttpModules and this issue still occurs, meaning it has nothing to do with the CMS portion of the system.

Comment: Silly question: but does /DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx actually exist?

Comment: That's the odd thing, it *does* exist, in the .NET 4.0 Framework\Config folder. I guess I've worked around the issue, now, so the issue remains unexplained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

There seems to be a new configuration added to web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <webServices>
        <wsdlHelpGenerator href="DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx" />
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Removed this, and it all works.

Answer (score 0):

No explanation here; I got the same error.

My fix was to run "iisreset" on the server, then reload the page, and it went away.